# What is the cosine/sine of a matrix good for?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, matrix-exponential

In an Advanced Linear Algebra class, we recently learned about the cosine, exponential and sine of a matrix - how to define it, how to find it, etc. However , we did not learn about the applications and the need for defining these concepts.
I have read in some places about how the exponential of a matrix is used in robotics (exponential coordinates) but what is the need for defining the cosine and sine? Is it just for fun?

Comment: The matrix exponential is useful for solving first order linear systems of differential equations. I'm not sure about $\sin$ and $\cos$, but I imagine they could correspondingly be used to solve second order linear systems, along with the matrix exponential.

Comment: This goes quite a lot deeper, but in functional analysis, the objects of study are linear maps from (typically infinite dimensional) vector spaces into $\mathbb{C}$ ,which are analogous to matrices.  Via a lovely set of theorems, we get something called the "functional calculus," which allows us to answer some deep questions about these objects using tools from calculus.  At its heart, the functional calculus is about understanding what $f(A)$ is, where $f$ is some "nice" function, and $A$ is a linear map, which you can think of as (roughly) a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Before I start, just take into account that when we evaluate a function in a matrix, we don't mean an entrywise evaluation (except for Octave and Matlab):
$$\text{If } A=[A_{i,j}] \text{ then } f(A)\neq[f(A_{i,j})].$$
For a real function $f$ with a Taylor expansion, we firstly define the matrix-equivalent of $f$ for diagonal matrices:
$$\text{If } D=\begin{bmatrix}d_1\\&d_2\\&&\ddots\\&&&d_n\end{bmatrix} \qquad \text{then } f(D):=\begin{bmatrix}f(d_1)\\&f(d_2)\\&&\ddots\\&&&f(d_n)\end{bmatrix}.$$
Next we generalize $f$ for non-diagonal matrices that have an eigendecomposition:
$$\text{If } A=P\ \Lambda\ P^{-1} \text{ where } \Lambda \text{ is diagonal, then }f(A):=P\ f(\Lambda)\ P^{-1}.$$
Exponential matrices are useful because the solution of
$$f'(t)=-A\ f(t)$$
is
$$f(t) =\exp(-tA)\ f(0) =P\ \exp(-t\Lambda)\ P^{-1} f(0),$$
given all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive.
Similarly, we can use the cos and sin matrices to express the solution of
$$f''(t)=-A\ f(t)$$
as
$$f(t)=P\ \cos(t\sqrt{\Lambda})\ P^{-1} f(0) +P\sqrt{\Lambda}^{-1}\sin(t\sqrt{\Lambda})\ P^{-1} f'(0),$$
again, given all eigenvalues $A$ are positive.
However, you can't relate $f$ with $\cos(A) =P\ \cos(\Lambda)\ P^{-1}$ nor $\sin(A) =P\ \sin(\Lambda)\ P^{-1}$ because we have $\sqrt{\Lambda}$ instead of just $\Lambda$.

I think matrices such as $\exp(-t\sqrt[4]{\Lambda})$, $\exp(t\sqrt[4]{\Lambda})$, $\cos(t\sqrt[4]{\Lambda})$ and $\sin(t\sqrt[4]{\Lambda})$ appear when solving $f^{(4)}(t)=-A\ f(t)$. (I did it once but I forgot.)

Now, I will just mention that matrices such as the Discrete Cosine Transforms and Discrete Sine Transforms (which are actually built as entrywise evaluations $[\cos(a_{i,j})]$, $[\sin(b_{i,j})]$) are useful as their columns pose as eigenvectors of some special tridiagonal matrices (Britanak, Yip and Rao; *Discrete Cosine and Sine Transforms: General Properties, Fast Algorithms and Integer Approximations*, $2006$) that arise when numerically solving some differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

**COMMENT**(*refused as a comment because "too long by 75 characters"*).-In functional analysis, the concept of function that operates in an algebra is defined as follows: Let $ y = f (x) $ a function , say, of $\mathbb R$ in $\mathbb R$. If in the algebra $ \mathcal A $ when forming $ f (M) $ it makes a sense then $ N = f (M) $ is well defined as a function of $ \mathcal A $  in $ \mathcal A $. A well known example is the exponential $f(x)=e^x$ which operates in the algebra $ \mathcal A_n $ of matrices $n\space\text {x } n$. I don't know if the functions sinus and cosinus operate on  $ \mathcal A_n $ (*maybe not because of* $|\sin(x)|\le 1$). French mathematicians call this "calcul symbolique" (see Katznelson theorem which is an extraordinary case concerning all analytical functions on the circumference $\mathbb T$).